# Recursive methods Java

Tags: java, recursion

Recursion always has been something I have a hard time with. I have a test tomorrow and he said there will be some Recursion on the test so I want to be prepared.

The problem I am trying to do says this:

Given a class `Rectangle` with instance variables `width` and `height`, provide a recursive `getArea()` method. Construct a rectangle whose width is one less than the original and call its `getArea` method.

So I know that in recursion you end up calling the method inside itself with a simplified rendition. Like, I know somewhere in `getArea(int n)` I will have to call `getArea(n - 1)`. I am just not sure what to do with `width` and `height`.

So I have this:

```
public int getArea()
{
   if (width == 1) {
      // Base case here. Not sure what to do for this.
      return 1;   // Maybe? I'm not sure.
   } else {
      Rectangle smallerRect = new Rectangle (width - 1);
      int smallerArea = smallerRect.getArea();
      return smallerArea + height + width;
   }
}
```

Can anyone help me better understand recursion or maybe how to go about thinking through a recursive function? Thanks.

Comment: So what should be the output? If you decrease the width by on and call the method again it will continue until width is 0?

Comment: Note that when you construct a new `Rectangle` the constructor will require *two* parameters to initialize the `height` and `width` instance variables, not just `width`.

Answer (score 3):

You've got the recursion itself right, with a base case and a recursive case, and a correct reduction of the parameter in the recursive call (except that, as the commenters have noted, you also need to specify the height of the new rectangle). It's only the geometry that needs fixing: `height` doesn't change during the recursion; what is the area of the base case rectangle, which has got width 1 and height `height`? And if you are told the area of the rectangle with width `width - 1` and height `height`, how much extra area do you get by adding a strip of width 1 and height `height`?

For later use: while mathematically correct, this is a terrible way to compute the area of a rectangle, so please don't do this outside of exam/homework situations :-)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?  It's basically just multiplying width by height with recursion...

```
public int getArea() {
    return getArea(width);
}

private int getArea(int x) {
    return x == 0 ? 0 : height + getArea(x-1);
}
```

Comment: This is best answer but do not confuse the hell out of poster, he is new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getArea()
{
   if (width == 1) {
      // Base case
      return height;   // Area = width(1)*height
   } else {
      Rectangle smallerRect = new Rectangle (width - 1, height);
      int smallerArea = smallerRect.getArea();
      return smallerArea + height;
   }
}
```